# Finding Inverse Modulo

Tags: encryption

I'm working on a challenge like this:

```
def weird_func(FLAG)
    enc_flag = [(a + b*i) % n for i in FLAG]
    return bytes(enc_flag).hex()
```

Although I know the FLAG prefix which is `flag{`, without knowing `a,b` and `n`, I find it hard to calculate the whole FLAG. Only `enc_flag` is given in hex. I tried to brute-force but it seems like `n` is too large, or maybe I'm wrong. Can anyone help me step-by-step with this problem?

Comment: Hint: $a + b \cdot i$ is a linear expression with 2 variables, with 2 of them, you have a system of equations enough to solve it. You may be already familiar with it in real numbers, now you just do it modulo $n$. (If $n$ is a prime, then it's a field just like real numbers).

Comment: What control do you have over FLAG?  Can you arbitrarily set the prefix?  Or, do you know the prefix but can't set it?

Comment: @poncho well I just guess that the FLAG will be in the same format as before, so I'm assuming that I know the first 5 characters, `flag{`.  I'm not familiar with this so finding `n` is tough to me.

Comment: @LilLee: assuming your code needs only an additional `:` to be executable with `FLAG` on the tune of `b"flag{"`, we can find a very likely maximum value for `n`, and it's not large. And you (not us) can find a minimum, further narrowing down the values of `n`. Then the first hint applies.

Comment: Hint: In python, given `c = (b * i) % n`, then `b_inverse = pow(b, n - 2, n)`, and `i == (b_inverse * c) % n`